# Ajax paginator with custom filters

Tags: ajax, laravel

I'm successfully adopted this guide: https://laraget.com/blog/how-to-create-an-ajax-pagination-using-laravel to my needs, it works, but pagination won't work if i apply my custom filters.

Let's start with routes/web.php:

```
// products routes
Route::get('products', 'ProductController@index')->name('CatalogIndex');
// sorting products with custom filters
Route::post('products', 'ProductController@Filters');
```

Then we're going to ProductController.php:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $products = Product::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(12);

    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $products_view = view('includes.products', compact('products'))->render();
        return response()->json(compact('products_view'));
    }

    return view('catalog.index', compact('products', 'power', 'area', 'source'));
}

    // filtering products
    public function Filters(Request $request, Product $product)
    {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            // using query builder here
            $prods = $product->newQuery();
            // sorting by price
            if ($request->has('order')) {
                if ($request->input('order') == 'default') {
                    $prods->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                } else {
                    $prods->orderBy('price', $request->input('order'));
                }
            }

// more filters omitted for readability

            $products = $prods->paginate(12);

            $products_view = view('includes.products', compact('products'))->render();
            return response()->json(compact('products_view'));
        }

        return abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }
```

Some javascript, that makes these filters work:

```
        $('body').on('click', '.pagination a', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var url = $(this).attr('href');
            getProducts(url);
            window.history.pushState("", "", url);
        });

        function getProducts(url) {
            $.ajax({
                method: 'get',
                url: url,
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#products').html(data.products_view);
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(jqxhr, status, exception) {
                    console.log('Error' + exception);
                }
            });
        }
```

Now is the question, normal pagination with ajax works just fine, if i don't apply any filter, but if apply the filter (select all products where power source equal to something, etc), then when i click on a pagination link, it just leads to my index method of ProductController on 2nd page ignoring my filters, also url changes to "products?page=2", i expect the following behavior -> when you apply source filter == somevalue, then clicking on 2nd page, it would display 2nd page of all products with applied source filter, now it shows just index method with simple sorting by created_at column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended using query strings and switched to GET method.

Answer (score 1):

You need:

on the blade partial appends the adicional parameters on the paginator like this:

```
  {!!  $products->appends(['param1' => 'val1', 'param2'=>'val2'])->links() !!}
```

And on your method index() do that:

```
 if ($request->ajax()) {
    return $this->filters($request, $product); 
}
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your http methods are mismatched. Try changing your route to a "get" instead of "post" and see if that fixes it